# How maintain sequence of occurence of numbers from ndarray into set using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, set

**The Scenario**

I'm trying to get the number of clusters a dataframe belongs to.
Whose Data type is `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` and data as below

```
records_Array = array([0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
```

Obviously while printing I see `[0 0 0 ..., 1 1 1]` in this format.

Now, I need the numbers only once, so I convert into set and then to List,

```
cluster_set = list(set(records_Array))
```

**The Output**

On printing cluster_set, I get `[0, 1, 2]`

> where as the clusters are in sequence of `0, 2, 1`

**Required**

I need some function / method, that preserves the sequence of `records_Array` and returns in `cluster_set`

Comment: You probably need `np.unique()`.

Comment: @Kasramvd  Tried that already `np.unique(records_Array)
array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want Pandas' `pd.unique` as it does not sort as it finds unique values.  Numpy's unique function does.

```
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])

pd.unique(a)

array([0, 2, 1])
```